# Android TextView changing textColor does not affect symbols ♭and ♯ ( it does affect other symbols, like ø)

Tags: android, textview, textcolor

[image]

Android TextView changing textColor does not affect symbols ♭and ♯ ( it does affect other symbols, like ø). I have tried to modify the text color in the layout, from the program.

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The code:

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class activity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("Normal text ♯ ♭, <sup><small>superscript  ♯ ♭</small></sup><sub><small>subscript  ♯ ♭</small></sub>"));
             tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_200)) ;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I tried here with `android:textColor="@color/red"` and `textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red))` and worked fine

Comment: Thank you @Estevanbs, I apologise for not being complete.I have edited the question. The example given reproduces the behaviour.